# Which methods are good to override when creating custom NSManagedObject subclasses?

Tags: iphone, core-data

The Core Data Programming Guide talks a lot about what *not* to override. So the question is: What is *good* to override?

Like I see it, I can't override -init or -initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:

So where else would be a good override point to set up some basic stuff? Or is it generally not needed to do custom initialization? Does the whole thing rely only on accessing properties which then start to do fancy things? So no custom initializations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often override the following methods:

```
-(void) awakeFromFetch
-(void) awakeFromInsert
-(void) willTurnIntoFault
-(void) didTurnIntoFault
```

Don't forget to call super implementations.
In Addition the following method should be overridden to process Objects after undo/redo

```
- (void)awakeFromSnapshotEvents:(NSSnapshotEventType)flags
```

[ADC](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003397-235678)

Comment: Interesting. So -awakeFromSnapshotEvents: is called every time when an undo/redo happens? Is that a "snapshot event"? (makes sense, almost)

Comment: exactly, a list of possible events can be found in the apple developer documentation